# should the value be returned as soon as it is found or iterate until the condition becomes false?

Tags: java, binary-search

I was trying to do a binary search on **sorted array** where the task is to find the single element as all other are repeating twice and there will be no case when there will be no single element i.e. there will be a single element in every case.

**eg:** int[] nums = {1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 8, 9, 9, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 21, 21, 26, 26};
**o/p** -> 15

**1st case :** Returning element as soon as the element is found

```
public int singleElement(int[] nums) {
        
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        int mid;
        
        while(start <= end){
            
            mid = start + ((end - start) >>> 1);
            // here this condition is checked every time it enters the loop
            if(nums[mid] != nums[mid + 1] && nums[mid] != nums[mid - 1])
                return nums[mid];
            
            if(nums[mid] == nums[mid ^ 1])
                start = mid + 1;
            else
                end = mid - 1;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
```

**2nd case:** With a single return and iterating until the condition becomes false

```
public int singleElement(int[] nums) {
 
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        int mid;
        
        while(start < end){
            
            mid = start + ((end - start) >>> 1);
            
            // no extra condition to check every time to return element as in the 1st case

            if(nums[mid] == nums[mid ^ 1])
                start = mid + 1;
            else
                end = mid;
        }
        
        return nums[start];
    }
```

**1.** I just want to know among these 2 approaches which one is better and why? 
**2.** And also is it better to run loop less than end(start < end) or less than equal to end(start <= end)?

Comment: If you return early, you avoid work. If you keep looping, you (or rather your CPU) are doing useless work.

Comment: @knittl: I am aware of your mentioned suggestion but if I write code for returning element, then I have to perform extra operations to return element in each iterations which is not the case with the 2nd case

Comment: @Andy: It is very much applicable if the elements are sorted... I am assuming that you have not read the description thoroughly!!!

Comment: Think about it this way: you find the 3rd element out of 1 million elements. That's 3 times checking the condition, then exiting the loop. With a full, you are avoiding the check for the first 3 elements (so for only 3 elements it is better), but then you are executing the second 999997 times. Unless you are expecting to inspect the full array in most cases, that's a clear win. On average you can assume the middle element to be found. Thats 500k checks (for the return) + 500k checks (for the actual computation). Without the return it is 1M checks (for the actual computation). No win there.

Comment: @knittl: Here, I am performing binary search i.e. O(log(n)) and not O(n) and for 1 million cases it will run for at most 20 times and not 1 million times or 999997 checks...

Comment: Oh, right. I have to admit that I was too fast to comment. I'd go without the extra check. The loop condition is already checked directly after the inner if. You are not gaining anything by doing an extra check (given that both implementations behave identically otherwise). But then, it's only 20 additional instructions, so it does not matter (unless you are calling this method millions of times per second and have identified it to be the bottleneck)

Comment: @knittl: It matters if 2 solutions have the same complexity as with the 1st case, 20 extra operations are being done but for not for 2nd case. Though the 2nd implementation can go for extra iterations but not more than 2 - 3 times which is comparatively much less than 20.

Answer (score 1):

If you're studying, teachers will, most likely, tell you not to use multiple returns, as they act like a "break", because they want you to think and work on the condition, and don't just leave the method or loop. Now I'd use the first, but when I was studying, I used the second. When you know how to code, you can use breaks, multiple returns, and whatever you want, but when you are learning, it is best to go slow and assimilate well the knowledge.

In terms of efficency, the first. In terms of adquiring knowledge, the second. The negative part of it is that when you have a lot of lines of code, and you have lots of returns and breaks, it can become complicated to follow the code and understand what it's doing, especially when the code isn't yours. But, definitely, the first.

Comment: I agree with your points... but to return the element (whenever it is found) also needs to check conditions in each iteration which is time consuming and which is not the case with the 2nd case...

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better, specially for big lists. Why would you need/want to iterate through the whole list?

Comment: But what about checking conditions in each iterations as it will consume time too which is not the case with the 2nd case (though it might more time)